# Putting a full-text search index on a view with a function

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I have a view that looks like this:

```
select ID, dbo.functionname(ID) from tablename
```

I'm trying to put a full-text index on this, but it doesn't seem to have a unique index that I can go off of. The tablename.ID is the unique identifier.

I tried creating an index on it, but it says it cannot schema bind view because the function is not schemabound.

What do I need to do to get the full text index created?

Comment: Have you tried to make it an indexed view? (so the results are stored on the db's filesystem) ?

Comment: I tried creating an index on it, but it says it cannot schema bind view because the function is now schemabound.

Comment: You have to add the schema name for being able to create the indexed view
select ID, dbo.functionname(ID) from [YourSchema].tablename

Comment: Hi Ajma, did this help? have you managed to get your view indexed?

Comment: Yeah, it helped. My function isn't deterministic. I have to find some time to figure out how to make it deterministic but at least I know what to do to proceed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to create an index view, the view must be deterministic, that is it must be the guarantied to be the same on every query of it.

Is your userfunction [deterministic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214775%28SQL.80%29.aspx)?

> User-Defined Function Determinism
>
> Whether a user-defined function is
>   deterministic or nondeterministic
>   depends on how the function is coded.
>   User-defined functions are
>   deterministic if:
>
> ```
> * The function is schema-bound.
>
> * All built-in or user-defined functions called by the user-defined
> ```
>
> function are deterministic.
>
> ```
> * The body of the function references no database objects outside
> ```
>
> the scope of the function. For
>   example, a deterministic function
>   cannot reference tables other than
>   table variables that are local to the
>   function.
>
> ```
> * The function does not call any extended stored procedures.
> ```
>
> User-defined functions that do not
>   meet these criteria are marked as
>   nondeterministic. Built-in
>   nondeterministic functions are not
>   allowed in the body of user-defined
>   functions.

Is your function SchemaBound?

```
alter function [dbo].[UserFunction] 
(@example int = 1 ) 
returns int
with schemabinding
as
begin
  return 1
end
```

Is your view SchemaBound?

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.UserView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ID, [dbo].userFunction
```

To create an indexed view you must first create a [unique clustered index(See FAQ a bottom)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean't "not" schemabound in the comments above
Recreate your view "WITH SCHEMABINDING"
Then create a unique clusterred index
as explained here http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1610
Then try adding your Full Text Index